# jquery create cookie and access it in vb.net

Tags: jquery, vb.net, jquery-cookie, httpcookie

I'd like to set a cookie with jquery and access it in server side code.

this is what I came up with so far:

in jquery:

```
$.cookie("MyKey", "MyData", { path: "/" })
```

in vb.net (serverside code):

```
If Request.Cookies("MyKey") IsNot Nothing Then
       Dim mystring As String = Request.Cookies.Get("MyKey").Value
End if
```

but I it returns nothing.
Is there a way to fix this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does debugging return? When/where are you setting the cookie? When do you try to get the value? In Page_Load?

Comment: tnx for answering...in the debugging  I see the cookie has the value of nothing but when I check this cookie with jquery it does have "MyData" value....In the page load of the page with jquery...in the page_loadComplete in code behind